# Object deconstruct all props with ...props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So if i have alot of different props for one component I wish i could do something like

```
const { ...props } = props;
```

instead of

```
const { prop1, prop2, prop3, ... } = props;
```

why isn't statement 1 valid? or am I doing the syntax wrong?

Edit: statement 1 is valid i see that was me being stupid now.

what im looking for is a programatic way to achieve statement 2 so i dont have to write out loads of props

Comment: Statement 1 *is* valid, it just doesn't do anything useful - it creates a new object with the same properties. I suppose one method to define standalone variables for every property would be to iterate and use `eval`, but that's a really bad idea.

Comment: it is valid and it can be useful if you need to modify it before passing it down, the normal prop objects are read-only. what you just did is essentially `const newProps = Object.assign({}, props);`

Comment: The question is, why do you want to do statement 1 and not 2?

Comment: ok so how would I deconstruct the object in a programatic way rather than writing them all out

Comment: You wouldn't, because dynamic variable names are quite a bad idea. Just keep doing what you're doing

Comment: I hesitate to mention the `with` statement in JS: it would essentially do what you need, but it is horrible, bad practice, and can't be discouraged enough! CertainPerformance is absolutely right: bad idea!

Comment: @AndyWilson Simplify your application so that you have fewer props? Also if you aren't using most of them, or at least not more than once, a simple property access is simpler than destructuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option one is useful if you are using [HOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), for example in React native, if you are making animated components you can go:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Text} from 'react-native';

class ComponentToBeAnimated extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {...other} = this.props;
        return (
            <Text {...other}>
                hello world
            </Text>
        )
    }
}

export const AnimatedText = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ComponentToBeAnimated )
```

Then when you instantiate `AnimatedText`, you can apply styles as if you were instantiating `Text`

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import { AnimatedText } from './AnimatedText';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title: {
        fontSize: 19,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
     },
});

export const Message = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <AnimatedText style={styles.title}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

See you can apply all the `Text` props you want from the HOC